# Unable to download spring boot dependencies, spring repo asking for credentials

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-repositories

Unable to mvn clean install spring boot project. Downloading dependencies failing with error  `Authentication failed for https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-bom/1.3.50/kotlin-bom-1.3.50.pom 401 Unauthorized`

Same POM and maven configurations worked earlier. All of a sudden facing this issue. Directly accessing the said repo is asking for credentials(attached image). Not sure how to proceed. Any help is much appreciated.

Note : Using https not http.
Just a thought. If it related to version upgrading(if older version are not being supported) many such internal dependencies are failing how to handle this.

[image]

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2020/10/29/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-fall-and-winter-2020

Comment: available on mvnrepository: [kotlin-bom 1.3.50](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-bom/1.3.50)

Comment: mvnrepository is not a maven repository ...  https://search.maven.org/search?q=kotlin-bom is the correct location to search for artifact in Central repository ... Also you should rmeote any repository definition from your project .... best would be also to post your pom file ...

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- reference you shared helped me understand why all of a sudden am not able to build.

Answer (score 0):

Changing mirror in settings.xml from SpringRepo to UK Central worked.  Used below mirror

```
   <mirror>
      <id>UK</id>
      <name>UK Central</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
```

Comment: where to put this code snippet? I am using JetBrains IDE for my code editing, not able to build my project.

Comment: Maven settings.xml file.. it can be found in maven installation directory > conf folder or .m2 repository folder created by maven